# Converted BAT to EXE Now Path to Temp Not Local

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, path, conversion, compile

After converting Test.bat to Test.exe the Test.exe not finding local input file 360_2016.mp4 and the EXE file CMD Prompt displaying its path is to TEMP not local directory/folder. The EXE file is not accepting drag and drop but is responding to double click.

What is needed is modification to Test.bat so Test.exe will find input file.

The BAT to EXE conversion was with 'iexpress'.

Here is Test.bat script:

```
echo off setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


echo AA echo %1 echo AAA echo %~dp1

set "FN=%~n1.mp4" echo: echo FN= %FN%
pause
```

From drag and drop on Test.bat here is the result from Test.bat at CMD Prompt:

```
C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\Test Area 9>echo off AA
"C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\Test Area 9\360_2016.mp4" AAA
C:\Users\canjm\Desktop\STUFF\Test Area 9\

FN= 360_2016.mp4 Press any key to continue . . .
```

From double click on Test.exe here is the result from at CMD Prompt:

```
C:\Users\canjm\AppData\Local\Temp\IXP000.TMP>echo off
AA
ECHO is off.
AAA
ECHO is off.

FN= .mp4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Here is 'iexpress' or bat_to_exe.bat script:

```
;@echo off
;Title Converting batch scripts to file.exe with iexpress
;Mode 75,3 & color 0A
;Rem Original Script https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/edit/master/hybrids/iexpress/bat2exeIEXP.bat
;echo(
;if "%~1" equ "" (
    ;echo  Usage : Drag and Drop your batch file over this script:"%~nx0"  
    ;Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & Exit
;)
;set "target.exe=%__cd__%%~n1.exe"
;set "batch_file=%~f1"
;set "bat_name=%~nx1"
;set "bat_dir=%~dp1"
;Set "sed=%temp%\2exe.sed"
;echo              Please  wait a while ...  Creating "%~n1.exe" ...
;copy /y "%~f0" "%sed%" >nul
;(
    ;(echo()
    ;(echo(AppLaunched=cmd /c "%bat_name%")
    ;(echo(TargetName=%target.exe%)
    ;(echo(FILE0="%bat_name%")
    ;(echo([SourceFiles])
    ;(echo(SourceFiles0=%bat_dir%)
    ;(echo([SourceFiles0])
    ;(echo(%%FILE0%%=)
;)>>"%sed%"

;iexpress /n /q /m %sed%
;del /q /f "%sed%"
;exit /b 0

[Version]
Class=IEXPRESS
SEDVersion=3
[Options]
PackagePurpose=InstallApp
ShowInstallProgramWindow=0
HideExtractAnimation=1
UseLongFileName=1
InsideCompressed=0
CAB_FixedSize=0
CAB_ResvCodeSigning=0
RebootMode=N
InstallPrompt=%InstallPrompt%
DisplayLicense=%DisplayLicense%
FinishMessage=%FinishMessage%
TargetName=%TargetName%
FriendlyName=%FriendlyName%
AppLaunched=%AppLaunched%
PostInstallCmd=%PostInstallCmd%
AdminQuietInstCmd=%AdminQuietInstCmd%
UserQuietInstCmd=%UserQuietInstCmd%
SourceFiles=SourceFiles

[Strings]
InstallPrompt=
DisplayLicense=
FinishMessage=
FriendlyName=-
PostInstallCmd=<None>
AdminQuietInstCmd=
```

Comment: nearly every "converter" is just a wrapper that creates the batch file in the temp directory upon execution

Comment: If the above doesn't make the solution clear: Don't rely on the batch files path, rather, use the fully qualified filepath of the dropped file: %~f1

Comment: I agree. I will replace my '%1' with '%~f1'